# Updating a huge war file without redeploying everytime - apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

**What I have done**

I have deployed a war file through tomcat admin panel and its working fine. As soon as I deploy the war file apache creates a seperate folder structure for it.

**What I want**

Now I want to update the war file without having to redeploy everytime.

**What I cant do**

I cant upload a new war file just for a minor change in a class, it is a heavy webservice with all the libraries and ancillary classes bundled so the size is quite huge which takes ages to upload.

**Weird Scenario**

When i delete the war file the folder gets deleted automatically(magically I mean), so I believe there is a strong attachment between the war and the fodler

I am using netbeans to develop a java webservice, if thats of any importance, thanks

I have searched every where but cannot find anything explained. Only heard of something like dynamic deployement [here](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFoQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fjavaee%2F6%2Ftutorial%2Fdoc%2Fbnadx.html&rct=j&q=dynamic%20deployment%20netbeans&ei=p8DpTefuH8mHhQeSt5y6Bg&usg=AFQjCNGH5e652zB2q9fvMGuxdIqFQH1UTw&cad=rja) but dont know how to enable it in netbeans

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok i got it, thanks alot alyo, i updated the compiled classes and reloaded the application from the tomcat manager and it started working, thanks for the help

Comment: what is wrong with doing something that saves you a hell lot of a time. Plus one should know that it could be done this way, I never knew I could do that

Answer (score 3):

it's in the tomcat config file server.xml (/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml - this depends on your installation)
there will be a similar line to this:

```
<Host name="www.example.com" debug="0" 
      appBase="/sites/www.example.com/web" unpackWARs="true" 
      autoDeploy="true">
```

Comment: is autodeploy by default set to true, coz i dint change it just replaced the updated war file there, thanks by the way

Answer (score 1):

You should set the tomcat config autoDeploy = true.

Then when you update the was file in appBase, tomcat should update the app automatically.

Comment: where can i find this tomcat config file? and by appBase do you mean the root of the application? or any other folder?